# Xcode Application Loader Error in CFBundleExecutable

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader, info-plist

[image]

App Loader suggested to delete CFBundleExecutable key so I did, and also changed CFBundlePackageType to BNDL. However, Application Loader gave an error stating that it could not find a CFBundlePackageType. So I changed it back to APPL, but then it gave another error stating that it does not contain CFBundleExecutable.

Therefore, I added back CFBundleExecutable and now it's back to the same ERROR message as it was from the start.

Comment: I had the same issue in 2 of my apps, You just have to delete CFBundleExecutable key from the Google Framework's .plist file. Only removing key from .plist is the solution.

Comment: @MilanGupta my good sir, which folder would I find that file? 

I tried editing a couple of info.plist files I found inside my project. Still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

@MilanGupta you're right I just have to delete CFBundleExecutable, but it's not the one under the project's Info.plist. I had to Cmd + Shift + F and then searched "CFBundleExecutable" there was an Info.plist under GoogleMaps.